# How to run multiple queries in row safely?

Tags: mysql, sql, aqua-data-studio

I have the below queries and i can run them one by one successfully,

```
Delete from eventor.user_role ;
Delete FROM eventor.role ;
delete from eventor.user ;
```

but when i run all of them together, it complains with the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Delete FROM eventor.role ;
```

This is a surprise for me since, i can run the

```
 Delete FROM eventor.role ;
```

successfully, and i have terminated all the queries using  `;`.

So, **why am i getting this, and how can i fix it?**

Comment: what are you using to run the query?

Comment: Delete foreign key table first then finally delete master table data

Comment: May be try a batch separator like 'GO' in between the statements?

Comment: i am running the query directly against mysql, using `Aqua Data`

Comment: Post the code you are using to execute all 3 together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.aquafold.com/support_faq#commands:

> Q: Scripts with multiple statements return errors, while each
>   statement can be executed individually without errors.
>
> Example:
>
> `select * from t1 select * from t2 select * from t3`
>
> This script returns errors.
>
> **Aqua Data Studio uses “go” or “/” symbols as line separators between
>   statements.** 
> Here is a corrected example of the same script:
>
> ```
> select * from t1
> /
> select * from t2
> /
> select * from t3
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> select * from t1
> go
> select * from t2
> go
> select * from t3
> go
> ```

Try using `go` or `/` instead of `;`

Answer (score 3):

- From **File**, choose **Options**, then **General**
- Check `**';' Statement separator`